# Django error xhtml2pdf

Tags: django, pdf-generation, xhtml2pdf

I am trying to generate a pdf with xhtml2pdf using a helper called django-xhtml2pdf but I am getting an error about the library xhtml2pdf. can you help me?

This is the error. thanks

```
SyntaxError at /

invalid syntax (util.py, line 302)

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version:     1.7.7
Exception Type:     SyntaxError
Exception Value:    

invalid syntax (util.py, line 302)

Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/xhtml2pdf/__init__.py in <module>, line 41
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     3.4.3
Python Path:    

['/home/ed/syscat',
 '/usr/lib/python34.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-linux',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
```

Comment: `xhtml2pdf` is reported not to work with Python 3. Here is the open ticket with links to other related tickets on [Github](https://github.com/chrisglass/xhtml2pdf/issues/223). To test if this is the problem you could try using the package with Python 2.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that, thanks for your answer.